# How to move to the bottom of Facebook permission dialog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, facebook-ios-sdk

In my app, I request permission: [publish_stream,offline_access] and the permission dialog show as [image]

I want the dialog show the allow button directly, just as following without scroll
[image]

Could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. File a bug @ https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and it will get reviewed.